# How to generate .apk for my cross platform application in visual studio 2015 (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin

I am currently making a cross platform mobile application . Where in I am targeting Android, IOS as well as the Windows OS.I have just made a hello world form and debugged it for android. Runs perfect on the emulator. Now want to send the .apk file to my coworker to see on her Android Mobile. How do i generate the .apk file???

Answer (score 2):

Right click on solution with Android app and click on Archive more [HERE](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/)

Comment: In addition to this, you'll also have to sign the apk, build as release, and her phone will have to be in developer mode.

Answer (score -1):

You have to run your application in release mode. The generated apk is located in the bin\release folder of the android project